# Table row gets deleted but value remains

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have Built a table in which the user does some calculations, but when any row gets removed the values entered appear in the row below it and the next row's value below it, and so on.
What I want is a the user removes any row it should get removed completely with the values entered and the next row should take its place with its own values.

Image 1:Here I have entered values in the First Two rows you can see in the image.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWUBE.png

Image 2: I deleted the first row but as you can see the value of that is still there.
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuOuA.png

**App.js**

```
 const [NewRow2, setNewRow2] = useState(data);

  const [IntensificationRatio, setIntensificationRatio] = useState(0)

  const [editFormData, setEditFormData] = useState({
    Injection_Speed: "",
    Fill_Time: "",
    Peak_Inj_Press: "",
    Viscosity: "",
    Shear_Rate: ""
  })

  const [isRowId, setIsRowId] = useState(null)


  const handleEditFormChange = (event) => {

    event.preventDefault();

    const fieldName = event.target.getAttribute("name");

    const fieldValue = event.target.value;

    const newFormData = { ...editFormData };

    newFormData[fieldName] = fieldValue;

    setEditFormData(newFormData);
  }


  const handleEditFormSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const editedValue = {
      id: isRowId,
      Injection_Speed: editFormData.Injection_Speed,
      Fill_Time: editFormData.Fill_Time,
      Peak_Inj_Press: editFormData.Peak_Inj_Press,
      Viscosity: editFormData.Fill_Time * editFormData.Peak_Inj_Press * IntensificationRatio,
      Shear_Rate: 1 / editFormData.Fill_Time,
    }

    const newValues = [...NewRow2];

    const index = NewRow2.findIndex((value) => value.id === isRowId)

    newValues[index] = editedValue;

    setNewRow2(newValues);

  }

 const deleteRow2 = (id) => {
    const updatedRows = [...NewRow2].filter((rowId) => {
      return rowId !== id;
    });
    setNewRow2(updatedRows);
  };
```

HandlEditchange and HandleEditSubmit are the two functions that deal with data entered in the row and deleteRow2 for removing the row.

**Table Row's**

```
 <tr onClick={() => setId(NewRow.id)}>

 <td> {rowId} </td>

 <td> <input type='text' className="form-control" name="Injection_Speed" onChange={handleEditFormChange}/> </td>

 <td> <input type='text' className="form-control" name="Fill_Time" onChange={handleEditFormChange}/> </td>

 <td> <input type='text' className="form-control" name="Peak_Inj_Press" onChange={handleEditFormChange}/> </td>

<td> <i className="fa fa-trash viscocity_icons" onClick={() => deleteRow2(NewRow.id)}></i> </td>
        </tr>
```

CodeSandBox Link: Rest You Can Check Over Here.

https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-gauss-lql7r?file=/src/Edit.js

Answer (score 0):

There were a few issues as I identified.

1. `handleEditFormChange` was not updating `NewRow2` state. You can fix it like below. Need to pass row `id` along with the event.

```
  const handleEditFormChange = (event, id) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    setNewRow2((prevState) => {
      return prevState.map((item) =>
        item.id === id
          ? { ...item, [event.target.name]: event.target.value }
          : item
      );
    });
  };
```

2. Need to change the `onChange` handlers like below.

```
onChange={(e) => handleEditFormChange(e, NewRow.id)}
```

3. Need to bind values from the `NewRow2` to each input.

```
value={NewRow.Injection_Speed}
```

same for `Fill_Time`, `Peak_Inj_Press`

4. `deleteRow2` should be using `id` correctly when filtering.

```
  const deleteRow2 = (id) => {
    const updatedRows = NewRow2.filter((item) => {
      return item.id !== id;
    });
    setNewRow2(updatedRows);
  };
```

5. Pass the `id` of the row to be deleted in the `onClick` handler.

```
onClick={() => deleteRow2(NewRow.id)}
```

Code sandbox => https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-hopper-zi8mw?file=/src/Edit.js:2738-2775

Comment: @suraj vishwakarma, check this out!!

Comment: @suraj vishwakarma, can you please mark this as the answer if it solved your problem?

Comment: it solve the problem i asked for but when i click on calculate all the rows get empty and no calculations get done.